# Auto-Updating python using requests and try except but not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, auto-update

I'm trying to add some update functionality to my python project I'm working on.

To do this I've first defined the project version at the top of my project.
I've then later got some code that inside of a try/except block visits a url through requests to get a version number.

The code is supposed to compare the two and if they do not match then offer the user the option to update and begin download of newer version.

My code skips the try/except block continuing past both without either executing.. What have I done wrong?

Note:I've left out some parts of the script for readability.

```py
    try:
        print("Checking for updates...")
        vercheck = requests.get(
            "https://pastebin.com/fMvQX8Nk").text.rstrip().split("|")
        if not vercheck[0] == selfbotversion:
            print(colored("There is an update available, Would you like to download it?", menucolour))
            verchoice = input("(Y/N): ")
            if verchoice.lower() == "y":
                clear()

                @animation.wait(colored('Downloading update, Please Wait ', menucolour))
                def run_update():
                    update = requests.get('https://github.com/redacted/redacted-redacted/archive/master.zip')
                    print("Update downloaded, Installing...")
                    return update

                update = run_update()
                with open("update.zip", "wb") as handle:
                    handle.write(update.content)
                try:
                    shutil.copy("config.py", "config_old.py")
                except Exception:
                    pass
                try:
                    shutil.unpack_archive("update.zip")
                    copy_tree("Public-master/", ".")
                    os.remove("update.zip")
                    shutil.rmtree("redacted-redacted-master/")
                    print("Update complete, exiting.")
                except Exception as e:
                    print("Error Updating, {}".format(e))
                time.sleep(3)
                sys.exit()
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error Updating")
```

If I do this code outside of the try/except block it runs so the problem must be something else..

```py
        vercheck = requests.get(
            "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/redacted/redacted-redacted/master/version").text.rstrip().split("|")
            if not vercheck[0] == selfbotversion:
        print(vercheck[0])
```

Any help is appreciated as I'm still learning python!
Thanks

Comment: I copied and pasted your code into a Python script and the try block is being called. I think the error is in the surrounding code. However, I believe the way you're calling the pastebin url is not the way you are hoping it is. The url you provided returns the complete html of the page containing your app version. If you want to receive just the pasted text you have to add a "raw" keyword in the url, such as https://pastebin.com/raw/fMvQX8Nk.

Comment: Ah yes @FelipeFerri, you're right. I'm actually using github for my version file but didn't want to post my link and thought it would make more sense if the link was viewable so in a rush pasted it in pastebin but forgot to copy the raw link!

Comment: And I was under the impression if the try block was being called it would have at least printed
```       
print("Checking for updates...")
```
if not asking if I'd like to update?

Comment: Can you add some of the surrounding code?

Comment: Not really sure what else to include? The code directly underneath what I pasted is the code that is working such as a print statement..
Above from it and removed from it is mostly just imports and other irrelvant parts to the code @FelipeFerri

Comment: It is working on my computer :-/ I don't think there is an error on that code (related to the try/catch block)

Comment: You're right! Sorry I didn't try the version of code I posted here beforehand! This is a less redacted version that is skipping the try/catch block.. 
https://pastebin.com/nJqgaGLU
Ideally I just want it to detect if the version number is different and if so download the new zip, extract it and confirm when the update is complete. @FelipeFerri

Comment: I can't open the pastebin link because it is private...

Comment: Oh sorry about that! I didn't realise private meant only I would be able to view it and I went to sleep after sending that! I've changed its privacy settings now. @FelipeFerri

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what I did to fix this in the end but I believe the issue came down to improper importing of modules.

I ended up just copy and pasting my code in chunks and fixing the errors as they came rather than loading it all together where I found it skipped printing a lot of the errors which were causing my problems in the first place!